# Is there a Loader.loadBytes() equivalent or solution for AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

If I have a handcrafted sequence of bytes, can I load them an AVM1 (flash8) swf using AS2, as I could do with Loader.loadBytes() in AS3? (Without roundtripping it to a server and loading it remotely).

Comment: can you explain please what do you want more detailed. thank you.

Comment: I assemble an AS2 swf bytecode by hand (the reason is not important) runtime-generated inside a Flash8 swf, and I would like to load the bytecode as a child swf. In AS3 I can do this with ease, not use if possible in AS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must conclude that this is impossible to do using AS2.

Answer (score 1):

You dont mean `LoadClip.BytesLoaded()`?  This is standard **AS2** for loading in exernal movie clips?